# Add a "What's next" section to Jobs template?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I love how Stack Overflow Jobs asks companies to answer the Joel Test—that's really helpful.

In the interest of guiding posters towards more complete and more useful job posts, would it be sensible to ask for a *"What's next"* section in job posts, expected to contain some bullets about the screening and hiring process?

It could contain anything the poster wants to say about their process, but I specifically, before spending time tweaking resumes and writing cover letters, would love to know about any soft-requirements like

1. the combination of phone calls, video calls, and in-person meetings that are expected or required;
2. whether an automated technical "screen" like HackerRank or Codility is required.

(1) above is more of a nice-to-know, so I can estimate the amount of time off I need if I hear back. (2) would be really useful because I personally don't take these tests (I wrote a [tiny rant](https://gist.github.com/fasiha/496d78a3ce9357cdec0a18f919407d2e)), and knowing such requirements would help me skip applying to some posts.

I understand that companies can be very flexible in how they meet with candidates, so #1 above could be only for soft-requirements, if any. I also understand that companies have myriad approaches to technical screeners, from

- automated tests like Codility/HackerRank, to
- in-person "whiteboard" interviews, to
- phone-based discussion,
- phone+[CoderPad](https://coderpad.io/),
- video+screenshare, etc.

and different applicants have vastly different tolerances for each of these, so #2 above would again be for soft-requirements.